# How can I have 3 tables joined without multiple listings?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, subquery

Here's what I can't figure out. I can get one join to work fine. The only way I can get more than 2 tables working is if I use a nested query inside my loop. How can I get results from a single query with multiple joins, but without getting multiple listings from my main table.

3 tables:
users: 2 users; 
projects: 2 projects; 
skills: 6 skills;

Using Codeigniter here, so I'll put the CI syntax.

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $this->db->join('user', 'user.id = projects.project_principal_id','left');
    $this->db->join('projects_skills_bridge', 'projects_skills_bridge.ps_project_id = projects.project_id','right');
    //$this->db->group_by('project_id'); // removed the multiple listing problem caused by the above JOIN
    $sql = $this->db->get();
```

Now when I loop through and get my projects (with user and skills info), I should get only 2 projects. The only way I can figure out how to get the skills associated with that project is to use a nested query within the loop (without the 2nd JOIN above), but I know that's sloppy. If I used the GROUP clause, I get only the 2 projects I want, but only the first skill instead of the several I want.

Output should be as follows:

Project Alpha by User Bob
 - skills: guitar, keyboards, bass

Project Beta by User Sally
 - skills: writing, html, invoicing

I'm sure this is a rookie problem, so thank in advance for taking a look.

Comment: can you put what output you want to get?

Comment: oops sorry, output added above. 2 projects listed only...not 6

Comment: I don't think this is possible with one line query. you can use loops(like what you are doing right now) or use ORMs.

Comment: you can only achieve: repeating projects with different skills on it, or distinct projects with a single skill.

Comment: OK. My misunderstanding. I was led to believe that a more complex JOIN or something might work. I'll keep with what I'm doing now. Thanks for the help !

Comment: You almost certainly should not be left or right joining. But you need to give the condition (predicate) for when a row is in each base table and in your desired result. Eg: projects holds rows satisfying "project [project_id] is by user [project_principal_id]". ([More.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690085/3404097)) Because if you don't clearly tell us what rows should be in the result how can we help you? Also table definitions. Also your keys and foreign keys, since your cardinality expectations might actually be unrealistic. Also table definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have something like:

```
 -- user [id] is named [name]
users(id,name)
-- project [project_id] named [project_name] is by user [project_principal_id]
projects(project_id,project_name,project_principal_id)
-- project [ps_project_id] requires skill [skill]
projects_skills_bridge(ps_project_id,skill)
```

Maybe you want these (project_name,name,skill) rows:

```
THERE_EXISTS id, project_id, project_principal_id,ps_project_id
    user [id] is named [name]
AND project [project_id] named [project_name] is by user [project_principal_id]
AND project [ps_project_id] requires skill [skill]
AND id = project_principal_id
AND ps_project_id = project_id
```

If so then just change `'left'` and `'right'` to `'inner'` in your current query. (Why are you using `'left'` and `'right'`?)

```
SELECT project_name, name, skill
FROM user
JOIN projects ON user.id = projects.project_principal_id
JOIN projects_skill_bridge ON projects_skills_bridge.ps_project_id = projects.project_id
```

If you want instead a row per project with its (presumably single) principal and a string of all its skills then you need to group the (inner) joins so there is one row per skill per project_id and select project_name, name and GROUP_CONCAT(skill).

```
SELECT project_name, name, GROUP_CONCAT(skill) AS skills
FROM user
JOIN projects ON user.id = projects.project_principal_id
JOIN projects_skill_bridge ON projects_skills_bridge.ps_project_id = projects.project_id
GROUP BY id, project_id
```

The chosen GROUP BY columns assure that there is only one row per skill per project_id, assuming id and project_id are keys in their base tables.

Comment: I think the GROUP_CONCAT is exactly what I am looking for. I'll work on it. Many thanks!

Comment: Be sure that you understand the definitions of (INNER) JOIN and LEFT and RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN. Note per above that the meaning of a JOIN of tables is the AND of the meanings of the tables. PS I just added some missing equalities in the THERE_EXISTS. (ON also means AND.) And... why were you using (LEFT & RIGHT) OUTER JOIN?