# ER Model (Chen notation)

Tags: database, model, entity-relationship, erd

My assignment is to draw an ER model (by hand) using Chen notation using the specifications below:

http://i57.tinypic.com/73ff2f.png

> If you have questions about these specs. I'll play the role of the
> client who will resolve them.
>
> The database will serve a university.
> Students have id's, names and gpa's. They must have exactly one major,
> but they could have minors as well. Each major or minor is a
> department which has a unique name and a phone number. For each
> student with a minor, we record the date she signed up for it. Faculty
> members are associated with a unique department and have id's, names
> and office locations. Each internship is held by a particular student
> at a particular compain and is supervised by a particular faculty
> member. We also keep track of the last term in which that student
> registered under that advisor for an internship at that company.
> Students may have many internships over time. A given faculty member
> may supervise many students at a given company, and she may supervise
> a given student at several companies. However, for a given student and
> company, there can be only one faculty advisor.
>
> Students, Departments,
> Faculty and Companies should be your entity types. Internship should
> be a ternary relationship type. The specs should also lead you to some
> binary relationship types. Don't add any ingredients to this mix other
> than what appear in the specs.

Below is my work:

http://i60.tinypic.com/28rf7tf.jpg

[image]

Can anyone please help as I really need a better understanding of this (my professor is AWFUL at explaining this).

Comment: What exactly is your question? your specifications link does not open anything and your work is barely clear

Comment: Sorry, I've been told handwriting is too light.

Comment: Anyways I just need guidance on how to draw an ER model (Chen notation) that meets those specs

Comment: You should ask specific questions you want answered. Yes or no whether you are missing something or wrong is specific but ways of doing things and instruction are open-ended. PS: You can always give the text equivalent of your diagram (a database schema).

Comment: I quibble with "each major or minor is a department".  That word "is" can lead you down the wrong trail when you are analyzing the subject matter.  The department "is" a group of faculty members, in every university I've ever seen.  A department "has" a field of study that can be a major or a minor.  I apologize for being so picky about words, but I've seen large database projects go seriously wrong because people were too fuzzy in their thinking about the subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

You missed (per your assignment's last paragraph) a department entity type.  (Box.)

You missed 'Faculty members are associated with a unique department'. That's a relationship between those two entity types. (Diamond with lines to those boxes.)

You could have those major and minor entitie types that are 1:1 with departments. (Your present boxes with each a line to its own diamond each with a line to department.) But (per your assignment's last paragraph not listing them as entities) you could have major being a relationship 'student[s] has a major in department [d]' and similarly for minor. (Lines from student to each of two diamonds each with a line to department.) But the assignment actually says 'each major or minor is a department' so that's major as 'student[s] has major department [d]' and similarly for minor. (Same picture.)

Per your assignment's last paragraph you should make internship a ternary relationship. (Under Chen it's a relationship diamond (possibly with its own properties) formed by 3 lines to entity type rectangles (possibly with their own properties) rather than an entity box.) However, it's not clear exactly when your assignment considers that an internship holds. (It tells us what relationships hold; it's just not clear which one it wants to call interning.) (Although we can look for interpretations consistent with it being ternary.) One is 'student [s] interns at company [c] supervised by faculty member [f]'. But since 'for a given student and company, there can be only one faculty advisor' that notion of internship is more simply characterized by a binary relationship 'student [s] interns at company [c]'. But then you still need a relationship 'faculty member [f] advises student [s] at a company [c]'. So I will suggest that your assignment expects the former. We can add property term. (This is more reasonably called a relationship on student, company, faculty member and date; but E-RM considers relationships to be on entities. Although it all depends on your class's method's particulars.)

(The possibility of multiple reasonable variations is why you should propose a particular design fully handling a particular specification in a SO question.)

A problem with the E-R Model [sic] is that it introduces needless distinctions between entities, reltionships and properties. There is really no distinction between a relationship instance and an entity. Eg: Here we could just as well have an internship be per above an entity in a 4-way relationship plus property. Eg: Your assignment says 'each major or minor is a department'. But a major or minor isn't a department. A major or minor could be considered a subject, which would be the subject after which a department is named or the subject of the degree offered by a department. Or we could just have relationships in which a department participates but the relationship is *about* that department's subject or name or degree being a major or minor.

(If an internship as relationship participated in its own relationships I don't know how your instructor's particular method would keep the further lines organized. Some methods add internship entities (box) 1:1 with relationships (diamond); then some methods specially associate the entity type with the relationship as a reification while some make the relationship 4-way by including the reified entity type. Eg 'internship [i] is student [s] at company [c] and ...'.)

(Correctly speaking there are entity types vs relationships and entities vs relationship instances. But the assignment talks of relationship "types".)

Re E-RM see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28124305/3404097) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690085/3404097). Also the [E-RM wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) section 'Entity–relationship modeling'. (Which correctly mentions misinterpretations of Chen's E-RM & E-RDs by some related modeling and diagramming methods and tools and even some presentations of E-RM itself. But the 'Overview' is nonsense.)

Re E-RM problems see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27272088/3404097).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is still have some questions... like how would I draw the "Faculty members are associated with a unique department" part?  Do I connect it to majors?  Minors?

Comment: You pick an entity type and add a box. You pick a relationship and add a diamond and lines. Hence... ({S: *Write out the predicates* for your application entities and relationships (and their properties). An entities get ids & predicate about them & their properties. Eg "[student_id] identifies a student with name [name] and ..." Relationships have predicates about their entities & properties. Eg above. Some words/things end up with corresonding entities (id attributes & predicates), relstionships (predicates) or properties (attributes).

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but with respect to my drawing, what would I do?